# How to check if a list is contained inside another list without a loop?

Tags: python, list, set

Is there any builtins to check if a list is contained inside another list without doing any loop?

I looked for that in `dir(list)` but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "contained". Maybe this:

```
if set(a) <= set(b):
    print("a is in b")
```

Comment: Seems functionally equivalent to my solution -- anybody know if either one has a performance advantage?

Comment: Not sure I buy that -- the call to `sub` is linear, but the `<=` can't be free.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Etaoin: `set` s are hashtables. Therefore the cost to access an object in a `set` is `O(1)`. In this code you have to go through all elements in `set(a)` (`O(len(set(a))`) and check whether this element is in `set(b)` (`O(1)`). But of course the overall cost us not (`O(len(sublist))`) as the sets have to build from the list first. I am not exactly sure what this costs but I think it should be `O(len(list))` so the overall cost is `O(len(a)) + O(len(b)) + O(len(set(a))`

Comment: Nice!  Thanks -- I was missing the constant-time access to sets.  +1 to your comment and this answer.

(Also, of course, in my last comment, `sub` was a brainfart for `set`.)

Comment: what if `a = [1,1,2,3]` and `b=[1,2,3]` ? `a` is not contained in `b` but your code says so.

Comment: @Adrien Plisson: That's why I said *Depends on what you mean by "contained"*.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming that you want to see if all elements of `sublist` are also elements of `superlist`:

```py
all(x in superlist for x in sublist)
```

Answer (score 14):

You might want to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```py
if set(a).issubset(b):
    print('a is contained in b')
```

Comment: Is there any advantage of your answer over [nosklo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582917/5376789)?

Comment: Yes, first there is no need to convert both `list`s to `set`s. Thus, my proposal saves one instruction (I've checked with `dis.dis()`). Also, because of the verbosity of the method `issubset` it is more readable.

Answer (score 6):

the solution depends on what values you expect from your lists.

if there is the possiblity of a repetition of a value, and you need to check that there is enough values in the tested container, then here is a time-inefficient solution:

```
def contained(candidate, container):
    temp = container[:]
    try:
        for v in candidate:
            temp.remove(v)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

test this function with:

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,3]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> contained(a,b)
False    
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> contained(a,b)
True
>>> a = [1,1,2,4,4]
>>> b = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5]
>>> contained(a,b)
True
```

of course this solution can be greatly improved: list.remove() is potentially time consuming and can be avoided using clever sorting and indexing. but i don't see how to avoid a loop here...

(anyway, any other solution will be implemented using sets or list-comprehensions, which are using loops internally...)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate that all the items from the list1 are on list2 you can do the following list comprehension:

```
all(elem in list1 for elem in list2)
```

You can also replace list1 and list2 directly with the code that will return that list

```
all([snack in ["banana", "apple", "lemon", "chocolate", "chips"] for snack in ["chips","chocolate"])
```

That any + list comprehension can be translated into this for a better understanding of the code

```
return_value = False
for snack in snacks:
   if snack in groceries:
     return_value = True
   else:
     return_value = False
```