# How many times specific list is found in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count

I have the following list

```
a = ['Bananas', 'Ananas', 'Peach', 'Grapes', 'Oranges']
```

and the following list of lists

```
b = [['Bananas', 'Ananas', 'Peach', 'Grapes', 'Oranges'], ['Bananas', 'Ananas', 'Peach', 'Grapes', 'Oranges', 'Pear', 'Apple'], ['Oranges', 'Strawberry', 'Pear'], ... ]
```

As you can see, inside of **b** it's possible to have

1. A list that's exactly the same as **a**
2. A list with the same items as **a** but in a different order
3. Similar to 1 and 2 but more items than **a**
4. Similar to 1 and 2 but less items than **a**
5. A totally different list than **a**

Considering that using

```
for value in b:
    print(value)
```

one is able to get each list of **b** which can then be compared to **a**,  how to know how many times cases 1, 2 and 3 occur (including duplicates)?

---

Inspired in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424456/5675325), I experimented

```
count_matches = 0

for value in b:
    ff = str(value).strip("[]")
    gg = str(a).strip("[]")
    if gg in ff:
        count_matches += 1

print(count_matches)
```

but this didn't work due to the order (for instances, other items could have been added in the middle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve it I combined [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2582917/5675325) with the for loop to get the value, as in

```
count_matches = 0
for value in b:
    if set(a) <= set(value):
        count_matches += 1
        print("a is in b")
```